# How to set the image in Background image in UIViewController in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

How to set the image in Background image(means how to paste the image in Background image). I took one image as a background image in UIViewController. Right now i want to put the another image in background image.i know how to put the image as a Background image in UIViewController.But i have no idea how to put the image in background image.I tried the code.But the image will not displayed in background image.This is my code.please help me any body.Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{

 backgroundImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-small.PNG"];

 audioViewBackgroundImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:backgroundImage];

 [self.view addSubview:audioViewBackgroundImage];


 mImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"muluguphoto.png"];

 mBackgroundImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 160, 150, 90)];

 mBackgroundImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:mImage];

 [audioViewBackgroundImage addSubview:mBackgroundImage];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add it to your viewDidLoad..

```
    UIImageView *newImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [newImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];//here else you can add image
    [self.view addSubview:newImage];

    UITableView *newTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [newTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:newTable];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to viewDidLoad

```
          self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

Comment: @brother Parvendra Kumar have u understand my Question.I already display "bg-small.PNG" this is my background iamge.now i want to set the another image like "muluguimage.png" this image was put in above background image.

Comment: @user3222991 Brother just replace your Images ...... Which image you want to set under image ... set those image as view's background image and which image want to show on Front (Create an image view and set another image on this ). This is the solution

Answer (score 1):

you have to set imageview above imageview in userinterface.like in photo.make proper heirARCHY!and set frame of imageview INDependentaly as you want.here is background image with logo image..[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you initializing mBackgroundImage two times?

Let's try the below code and let me know the result.

```
    UIImageView * audioViewBackgroundImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    audioViewBackgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-small.PNG"];

    [self.view addSubview:audioViewBackgroundImage];


    UIImageView * mBackgroundImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 160, 150, 90)];

    mBackgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"muluguphoto.png"];

    [audioViewBackgroundImage addSubview:mBackgroundImage];
```

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your response.I try your code.But it is not working.my requirement is "bg-small.PNG" this is my background image.nothing but under image. and "muluguphoto.png" this is my front image.this is my requirement

Comment: Please check the image file name and Whether it is exist in app bundle? Did you set imageView background color to clear color? Does those two images has same size? Are you want to draw the second image over the first image? Paste your result screen shot if possible.

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView * bgImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg.png"];
[self.view addSubview:bgImage];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgImage];

Answer (score 0):

//write this line in viewdidload and make sure that you have import the image in your project by copying it .

when you write this line of code then this image will automatically replace the previous background image

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stack.jpeg"]];